# In case i have class with only one static variable - should i declare this class as static?

Tags: c#, .net

This is my class how hold my last visited Path:

```
public class LastPath
{
    private static string _lastPath;

    public static string lastPath
    {
        get { return _lastPath; }
        set { _lastPath = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: your code is fine dont make getter setter just make it public field

Comment: One thing to keep in mind: A Settable property on a Static Class _may_ indicate a design where you rely on global/shared mutable state which can lead to some subtle bugs (someone, somewhere set this to some other value and now stuff is breaking somewhere else). Impossible to say without knowing the exact code, just something to ponder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all members of a class is static and your class is not meant to instantiated it should be `static`.

In this case your class satisfies the above rule or guideline so marking it as `static` will make sense because you don't have any instance member.

```
LastPath path = new LastPath();
path.????//  Nothing to access, so prevent instantiation by marking class static.
```

Being said that If you have only one field in your class and no methods I'd argue that you probably don't need a class at all, just refactor it to some other class where it would make sense.

Answer (score 2):

I would say you to do this:

```
public static class LastPath
{
    public static string lastPath
    {
       get;set;
    }
}
```

You should declare it as `static` as static classes cannot be instantiated, while non static classes can be instantiated, which is not needed.

Comment: What's wrong with my get\set ? what's the differences between the both ?

Comment: @user3328870, the difference is nothing. You don't need to create a separate field and all those things. C# will do it for you ;)

Answer (score 2):

make the class static and make a public property as static and you are done, like this:

```
public static class LastPath
{

    public static string lastPath { get;set;}

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with my get\set ? what's the differences between the both ?

Comment: your's is also fine but in .net framerwork 3.5 and above you can make getter setter like this without making a private field

Answer (score 1):

First - it looks odd to me to create class for holding single variable. Consider to use simple string variable `lastVisitedPath` instead. If you use this variable in single class, then make it field of that class.

Second - naming is not very readable. Here is how getting last path looks like: `LastPath.lastPath`. You see this useless duplication? Also keep in mind, that due to Microsoft naming guidelines public members should have Pascal Case names. Consider to create class with descriptive name like `GlobalValues` or `Cache` which reflects its purpose:

```
public static class GlobalValues // holds values which are globally accessible
{
   public static string LastVisitedPath;
   // other global values
}
```

So that usage will look like `GlobalValues.LastVisitedPath` or `Cache.LastVisitedPath`. Of course, if these classes don't supposed to be instantiated, they should be static.